# How-Where should I end this partial skirt-board at the stair? (I have more wood to re-cut a new piece if need be)

Tags: stairs, basement-refinishing

**Stairs into basement**

I'm not sure how the skirt-board should mate into the base molding? (Is this correct?)

And most important, where should I end the vertical cut from the stair nose (see arrow below)?

The wall will just be finished smooth with a drywall corner piece and mud finishing off the wall and ceiling.  I'm not planning on putting in trim at this time.

The original contractor had cut the tread too short and I thought this would be a great finish to a mistake I'm stuck with.

[image: Stair Skirt board issue]

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a perfectly good solution as pictured. You could, I suppose, run a little longer at the yellow arrow, but I don't think you'd want to go all the way to a point.

The only thing that offends this trim carpenter is the direction of the grain... I'd have done it in line with the angle of the stairs. (So no end grain on top.)

But a bit of paint, coupled with the fact that this is the stairwell to the basement and anybody else looking at it will think it's marvelous... well, I'd say you're done.